# How to convert MultiIndex Pandas dataframe to Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, multi-index

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe that is MultiIndexed on two variables (an ID and a DateTime variable) to dask dataframe however I get the following error;

```
"NotImplementedError: Dask does not support MultiIndex Dataframes"
```

I am using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

dask_df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df)
```

Actually, I have over 700 pandas dataframes (each over 100 MB) I am planning to convert each pandas dataframe into dask and then append them all to one big dask dataframe to analyze the whole data. I think the MultiIndex thing is the only issue here. Please let me know if I am going the wrong way about this.

Comment: Be aware that while dask seems to support multi-level columns, they have some behaviour differences and might be best to avoid too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Dask DataFrame does not support dataframes with MultiIndexes.

You might consider converting all but one of your index columns into normal columns with `reset_index`.